# How to load .txt into canvas

Tags: javascript

i'm not to bad at javascript myself but i am wondering for a few days at this moment wheter it's possible or not. And if it is, who can help me ?

*i need to build a single page application , and i am at the early phase. 
now one part where i am stuck at the moment is.*

**i wish to load different kind of questions into a canvas.**

=> java of the canvas

```
var Question = 'questions'; //<= **this is the part that needs to be corrected**

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = 'italic 18px Arial';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx. textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';  // a color name or by using rgb/rgba/hex values
  ctx.fillText(Question,100,50)// text and position
```

to be more clear. 
i have let's say 10 questions. i want to load them one by one into the canvas by clicking a button. **but i can't figure out how to load .txt files into the canvas can anyone PLEASE help me ?**

thanx in advance , any help would be much appriciated

Comment: Use XMLHTTPRequest to request the text file, load the response into a string, then pass it into `fillText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to issue AJAX GET request, load text file data, and use response text as a question. Something like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'question.txt', true);

request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
        var Question = request.responseText;
        ctx.fillText(Question, 100, 50)
    }
};

request.send();
```

This is a basic idea. I guess, depending on file contents you might want to process response text somehow before rendering on the canvas.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3OX8xI7h43CSlcuWowQ5?p=preview

Comment: Thanx , this goes into the direction i was going... I think i'll be good from here on 

god bless you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You just need 1) a list of questions and 2) to reset the canvas when setting a new question:

```
var questionIndex = 0;
var questions = [
        "question 1",
        "question 2",
        "question 3"
    ];

function nextQuestion() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.font = 'italic 18px Arial';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';  // a color name or by using rgb/rgba/hex values
    ctx.fillText(questions[questionIndex++], 100, 50)// text and position
    if (questionIndex > questions.length - 1) {
        questionIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

..

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<input type="button" id="btnNext" onclick="nextQuestion()" value="Next Question" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oehq2c0p/

Comment: this is a correct way to implement multiple questions yes , but it's not flexible since all questions are hardcoded 

but thanx ^^